# My Stack Overflow Careers profile disappeared after an account merge

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, merge-accounts

I had two accounts on Stack Overflow. After they were merged, my Stack Overflow Careers profile disappeared.

Here is my landing page, but without profile: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/468757

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I just merged your accounts and your profile is now available!